# Overriden MvxAndroidSetup.CreateIocProvider breaks binding with MvxBind:Error: View type not found - LinearLayout (TextView, EditText...)

Tags: android, xamarin, ninject, mvvmcross

I have a couple of PCLs which use Ninject for IoC. And now I am trying to create an Android Xamarin project with MvvmCross. The [guide](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control#what-if-i-want-to-use-a-different-service-location-or-ioc-mechanism) says I can follow two steps and continue using Ninject instead of MvvmCross implementation.

Here is my Setup.cs:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    ...

    protected override IMvxIoCProvider CreateIocProvider()
    {
        return new NinjectMvxIocProvider(... some NinjectModule[]...);
    }
}
```

And I took the implementation of NinjectMvxIocProvider [here](https://github.com/migrap/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Ninject/blob/master/src/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Ninject/NinjectMvxIocProvider.cs).

It look quite okay for me, but causes this kind of output for all views that are in my layout:

```
MvxBind:Error: 70.85 View type not found - EditText [0:]  
MvxBind:Error: 70.85 View type not found - EditText  
11-02 15:56:05.872 I/mono-stdout( 4824): MvxBind:Error: 70.85 View type not found - EditText
```

and bindings do not work, though ViewModels are created correctly with proper service implementations.

If I remove `override IMvxIoCProvider CreateIocProvider()` from `Setup.cs` the binding works.

Is there something wrong with this implementation that I just cannot see? Maybe someone has another implementation and is ready to share?

Comment: I think this is a bug in the ninject wrapper - it provides empty implementations for two key callback methods - see https://github.com/migrap/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Ninject/blob/master/src/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Ninject/NinjectMvxIocProvider.cs#L19 - you can fix this by editing the wrapper to store the callbacks - then using some mechanism to call the all callbacks during the last step of the build process.

Comment: @Stuart, that is exactly what I did just before reading your comment! I was inspired by your `MvxSimpleIoCContainer`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What about doing the setup something like this?

```
public static class App
{
    public static StandardKernel Container { get; set; }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(new NinjectDemoModule());           

        App.Container = kernel;
    }
}
```

Then for resolving:

```
var viewModel = App.Container.Get<MainViewModel> ();
```

Here is a working sample: [IoC Containers with Xamarin](http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/)

Comment: Your approach makes sense in case there is no need to use MvvmCross. It has a build in mechanism on resolving and instantiating ViewModels, so I don't have to do it manually. I just have to configure it providing `IMvxIoCProvider` implementation.